# PhpDocumentor on Laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpdocumentor2

How to use phpdocumentor in **laravel 5** is there any simple way to generate documentation other than via  CLI

Answer (score 3):

The best one to cater your requirement is [ApiGen](http://www.apigen.org/).

Comment: I do understand your point but I want to use phpdocumentor Anyways thanks for your suggestion